# Ajax tool kit deployment issue

Tags: asp.net

I am having deployment issue with AjaxControlToolKit.dll. I copied the DLL to my local bin dir, and it works fine. But when I do the build on test server, the files are not in Visual Source Safe anywhere, so the site doesn't work. What could be the issue?.

Thank you..

Comment: How are you deploying your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either check in the AjaxControlToolkit assembly and any dependencies it has, or you can install it (if there is an installer) on your build and test machines. Checking it in is preferred in most cases as it makes it obvious that you have this dependency. Rather than putting it in your .\Bin folder, make a .\References (or similarly named) folder and put it there along with any other binary references you have. Then, you can add a reference at that location and set it to "Copy Local".

Comment: Could you please tell me more details?

Comment: When we deploy the build, the bin dir on test server is remade for each build.

Comment: Do I have to check in AjaxControlToolkit.dll and other supported files to VSS?